# PHP Suhosin extension is not loading

Tags: php

For some reason i have to adjust the suhosin.request.max_vars and suhosin.post.max_vars directives.

I'm using ispCP, and it has default the suhosin patch, but as i read, i need to install the extension too. I've did this with apt-get install php5-suhosin and the suhosin.ini appeared in conf.d, and suhosin.so exists too in /usr/lib/php5. After the Apache restart the extension isn't loading.

According to `phpinfo()`, the directory `/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d` is scanned for additional ini files. List of .ini files parsed:

```
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/adodb.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/curl.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/eAccelerator.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/gd.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/idn.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/imagick.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/imap.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/memcache.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mhash.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/ming.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mysql.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mysqli.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/pdo.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/ps.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/pspell.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/recode.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/snmp.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/sqlite.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/tidy.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/xmlrpc.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/xsl.ini
```

As you can see, it doesn't loads the suhosin.ini.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's several things to check

- File permissions, make sure the apache user can read all the suhosin files, I assume you installed as root so this can be a real issue
- Some library problem while trying to load the extension. Check your error_log for any details regarding that

That's all I can think of for starters, let me know how it goes!

Comment: Checked the log earlier, nothing related in it. I've installed as root, but all the other .ini and .so files has root owner and the same permissions, so that can't be a problem.